# duplicated url_prefix in Flask using blueprint

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Sorry I've searched inside the stackoverflow and googled, but no useful information found.
I have an flask application,
python version 2.6
flask version 0.9

its application hierarchy is like

```
  application/
     __init__.py
     app.py
     hello/
       __init__.py
       view.py
       templates/
         hello.html
```

both files **init**.py are empty

```
app.py
-----------------------
from flask import Flask
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from hello.view import hello

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True 

app.register_blueprint(hello, url_prefix='/hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(app, bindAddress='/tmp/app.sock').run()
```

---

```
view.py
-----------------------
import os
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, abort
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

hello = Blueprint('hello', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@hello.route('/')
def get_index():
    try:
        return render_template('hello.html')
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
```

---

```
hello.html
-----------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            {% block body %}
            <h1><a href="{{ url_for('hello.get_index') }}">Click Me</a></h1>
        {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine when I enter `localhost:8080/hello`, but turns out error if I click the link in html. I found its url value is `href="/hello/hello/"` (Should it be `/hello/` right?).
I know hello.get_index is mapped to `/hello/`, but have no idea that the first one `hello/` comes from. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I've started an app using your code (but with `app.run()` instead of `WSGIServer(...).run()`), and the link is fine. Assume the issue somehow related to WSGI

Comment: Thanks a lot for your test! I will look into WSGI to see what caused this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing the url_prefix parameter when you regisger the blueprint? For example, what if you change the following from :

```
app.register_blueprint(hello, url_prefix='/hello')
```

to

```
app.register_blueprint(hello)
```